# Reordering html calculator buttons with css grid (using sass)

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

Hello all I'm trying to figure out why CSS grid doesn't reorder my calculator buttons. What I should get is something like that :

```
7 8 9 /
4 5 6 *
1 2 3 -
0 + = del
```

Or I just get the HTML order. Doesn't grid reorder the items ? (I know well of other ways to do this, I'd like to figure out why grid isn't working like I think it should...)

[See full code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/joelobrecht/pen/BamqdQE)

Here is the HTML code :

```
 <main class="calculator">
    <div class="result_screen"> </div>
    <div class="enter_screen"> </div>
    <div class="keyboard"> <button type="button" value="0" class="zero">0</button>
        <button type="button" value="1" class="one">1</button>
        <button type="button" value="2" class="two">2</button>
        <button type="button" value="3" class="three">3</button>
        <button type="button" value="4" class="four">4</button>
        <button type="button" value="5" class="five">5</button>
        <button type="button" value="6" class="six">6</button>
        <button type="button" value="7" class="seven">7</button>
        <button type="button" value="8" class="eight">8</button>
        <button type="button" value="9" class="nine">9</button>
        <button type="button" value="/" class="divide">\</button>
        <button type="button" value="*" class="multiply">*</button>
        <button type="button" value="-" class="minus">-</button>
        <button type="button" value="del" class="delete">C</button>
        <button type="button" value="=" class="equal">=</button>
        <button type="button" value="+" class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

Here's the SCSS :

```
    @mixin attribZones($zone) {
    .#{$zone} {
        grid-area: $zone;
    }
}


$zones: "zero",
"one",
"two",
"three",
"four",
"five",
"six",
"seven",
"eight",
"nine",
"divide",
"multiply",
"minus",
"delete",
"equal",
"plus";

@each $zone in $zones {
    @include attribZones($zone);
}

.keyboard {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "seven eight nine divide"
        "four five six multiply"
        "one two three minus"
        "zero plus equal delete"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove quotes when you define `$zones`.

```
$zones: zero,
one,
two,
three,
four,
five,
six,
seven,
eight,
nine,
divide,
multiply,
minus,
delete,
equal,
plus;
```

Because when you set `grid-area` to `$zone` you are essentially setting it to `"one"`, `"two"`... which are invalid values it has to be `one`, `two` ...

Comment: Thanks that was definitely the reason. I guess I was fooled by the syntax coloring that wasn't following the scss.